# Need users to Remote in

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to make the vpc unreachable to outsiders, but connectable for my end users?

Background: I have have created vpc and an instance that contains a server. It is possible to remote into for the end users, but it can also be seen by the world. My firewall rule lets users within my public IP remote into the virtual server for their remote session, but for the WFH users outside my public IP, they can not do the same. If this sounds idiotic, please say so. I'll go hire a contractor to do this. My company is trying to save money by having an inexperienced help desk, me, set all this up.

Comment: Setup a VPN to access resources in the VPC. You do need to know what you are doing with networking and security. A quick/cheap setup might save money up front and then waste valuable employee time with endless problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make use of "[IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap)" - Identity Aware Proxy.  It allows you to grant access to a VM based upon the Google account the user is logged in with.  Follow the instructions which require setting up a firewall rule as well as providing users with a specific set of permissions to use IAP.  It works very well.